# Determine if sub string appears in a string by row of dataframe

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a dataframe that is revised every day. When an error occurs, It's checked, and if it can be solved, then the keyword "REVISED" is added to the beginning of the error message. Like so:

```
ID  M1               M2                M3        
1   NA               "REVISED-error"   "error"    
2   "REVISED-error"  "REVISED-error"   NA        
3   "REVISED-error"  "REVISED-error"   "error"   
4   NA               "error"           NA         
5   NA               NA                NA
```

I want to find a way to add two columns, helping me determine if there are any error, and how many of them have been revised. Like this:

```
ID  M1               M2                M3         i1   ix
1   NA               "REVISED-error"   "error"    2    1    <- 2 errors, 1 revised
2   "REVISED-error"  "REVISED-error"   NA         2    2
3   "REVISED-error"  "REVISED-error"   "error"    3    2
4   NA               "error"           NA         1    0
5   NA               NA                NA         0    0
```

I found this code:

```
df <- df%>%mutate(i1 = rowSums(!is.na(.[2:4])))
```

That helps me to know how many errors are in those specific columns. How can I know if any of said errors contains the keyword REVISED? I've tried a few things but none have worked so far:

`df <- df%>%
mutate(i1 = rowSums(!is.na(.[2:4])))%>%
mutate(ie = rowSums(.[2:4) %in% "REVISED")`

This returns an error `x must be an array of at least two dimensions`

Comment: What defines an error? What does 2 mean here? `1   NA         REVISED-x   X     2    1`

Comment: @NelsonGon What do you mean? The errors are strings like this `This is an error` if i fix the issue, the I add `Revised_This is an error`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Alright, what of the `ix` and `i1`, what are they supposed to show? It seems to me that `NA` does contribute to `ix` in some way but not really clear.

Comment: @NelsonGon i1 is supposed to sow how many errors are by row (For the example, ID 1 has 2 errors) and ix shows how many errors have been revised (For the ID 1, only one of its errors has been revised, so 1) and so forth. The NA's are considered no errors, I mean if its empty, then there's no errors

Comment: @NelsonGon hope the edit makes more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `apply` to find number of times `"error"` and `"REVISED"` appears in each row.

```
df[c("i1", "ix")] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) 
                  c(sum(grepl("error", x)), sum(grepl("REVISED", x)))))


df
#  ID            M1            M2    M3 i1 ix
#1  1          <NA> REVISED-error error  2  1
#2  2 REVISED-error REVISED-error  <NA>  2  2
#3  3 REVISED-error REVISED-error error  3  2
#4  4          <NA>         error  <NA>  1  0
#5  5          <NA>          <NA>  <NA>  0  0
```

---

Althernative approach using `is.na` and `rowSums` to calculate `i1`.

```
df$i1 <- rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]))
df$ix <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) sum(grepl("REVISED", x)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, M1 = structure(c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), 
.Label = "REVISED-error", class = "factor"), 
M2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("error", 
"REVISED-error"), class = "factor"), M3 = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = "error", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @Ronak_Shah  If the text of the errors vary, can i still use the `!is.na()` approach?

Comment: @aaronparrilla as far as I have understood the question. `!is.na` would give you how many errors did not occur. It cannot give you a separate count of error occurred and error revised.

Comment: @Ronak_Shah the thing is that the errors dont say only error, they have some arbitrary text. If i find any value in that specific range of columns, it means someone has created an error message, therefore, if it's not NA, then it's an error. Thats why I ask

Comment: @aaronparrilla ok..I added an approach using `!is.na` to calculate `i1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_count()` from the `stringr` library to count the number of times `REVISED` appears, like so

```r
df <- data.frame(M1=as.character(c(NA, "REVISED-x", "REVISED-x")),
                 M2=as.character(c("REVISED-x", "REVISED-x", "REVISED-x")), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(stringr)
df$ix <- str_count(paste0(df$M1, df$M2), "REVISED")

df

#          M1        M2 ix
# 1      <NA> REVISED-x  1
# 2 REVISED-x REVISED-x  2
# 3 REVISED-x REVISED-x  2
```